# ACSL annotations on C macros

Tags: c, static-analysis, c-preprocessor, design-by-contract, frama-c

Is it possible to annotate C macros with ACSL?

eg:

```
/*@
    assigns \nothing;

    behavior xmin:
        assumes x < y;
        ensures \result == x;

    behavior ymin:
        assumes y <= x;
        ensures \result == y;

    disjoint behaviors;
    complete behaviors; 
@*/
#define min(x,y) (x < y ? x : y)
```

or even function calls such as

```
#define min(x,y) __min(x,y)
```

I already tried it, but with no success. Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Frama-C pre-processes source code with `gcc -C -E -I.`. After this pre-processing, the contract you offer as your first example does not make sense any more (see the pre-processed file for yourself by typing `gcc -C -E -I.` yourself). What I do is transform such macros into functions for the purpose of annotating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a flag in frama-c that allows the pre-processing of macros: `-pp-annot`. Automatically unfolding all macro calls, so you don't need to annotate the macro, this is done where needed in the functions that uses those macros.

Simple example:

```
#define min(x,y) (x < y ? x : y)

/*@
    requires 0 <= x <= 100000 && 0 <= y <= 100000; // for overflow...
    assigns \nothing;

    behavior xmin:
        assumes x < y;
        ensures \result == 2*x;

    behavior ymin:
        assumes y <= x;
        ensures \result == 2*y;

    disjoint behaviors;
    complete behaviors; 
@*/
int double_of_min(int x, int y){
    int a = min(x,y);   
    return 2*a;
}
```